# draw a horizontal line that is gradient/faded in color at both ends

Tags: android

i would like to draw a line 1px wide that is gradient at both ends. I can use an image instead but would like to do this with xml drawing in a relative layout.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this in the `<shape>` XML:

```
<gradient
    android:angle="0"
    android:startColor="#000000"
    android:endColor="#000000"
    android:centerColor="color_you_want" />
```

And then set your view to use the drawable as a background, 1dp thick